# reverse-i-search not showing all results compared to grep

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, search

I have always used reverse-i-search to grab my old commands, however for some reason its not returning all the results, at least the results I am expecting.

**desired command**

```
cat ~/.bash_history | grep tag
   git tag -a 1.0.52 -m "bump 1.0.52"
```

**Failed i-search**

```
(failed reverse-i-search)`tag': git push --tags
```

This failed search is after hitting cntrl-r three times. There are at least 50 results in my grep.

Comment: Are you using `history -c` command?

Comment: The in-memory and on-file history are separate, and can have different max numbers of lines. They are only synched on demand or exit.

Comment: Humm ok, its just for example I have used `demo` many many times, this is in my history of that I am sure. But I cannot find it. So I will search how to edit my on-file history then. Unless i-search uses memory? I have never used history -c in my life :)